# Two var as true in an IF statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am trying to figure out how I can use those two `var`s:

```
var s = document.getElementById('styledselect1');

var d = document.getElementById('styledselect2');
```

and check with an `if` statement if both of them are equal to a certain number, like below:

```
if (s.value == 0 and d.value == 5)
```

How can I declare this `and` between these two values?

`styledselect1` and `styledselect2` are select options..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 2):

Just use `&&` instead of `and`.

```
if (s.value() == 0 && d.value() == 5)
```

There are more "logical operators" than just `&&`. For example, there is `||` (or) that would only return `true` if at least one statement is true, `^` that would only be `true` if exactly one of the statements is `true`. Also, there is `!` (in front of a statement) that inverts the statement(makes `true` to `false` and `false` to `true`.

If `value()` is actually a number, I would suggest you to use `===` as it will be false for the same string.

Comment: These two vars (s and d) are returning the result from two select options that I need to be certain choices.

Comment: I thought you wanted to get the number as text